How can I get accessed to the data stored by gnome-pomodoro app?
I want to access the data store by gnome-pomodoro app. I want to do some basic analysis on it. but I can not find where it stores its data.
I know that it is installed in /usr/bin/gnome-pomodoro. But there is not stored data in that directory

Users apps usually store data in your user directory ($HOME), have you looked; eg. ~/.local/share/ maybe where I'd start ... I see details there for gnome-boxes; gnome-software, gnome-shell, gnome-sudoku & other gnome apps I do have installed...   Please note that's not the only place I'd look, maybe the first though, but I'm not familiar with that app sorry; config files maybe in ~/.config etc

@guiverc Yes it was there under ~/.local/share/ directory. the data was stored in sqlite.

Look at the strings in the executable. strings usr/bin/gnome-pomodoro.

Gnome Pomodoro stores its data in ~/.local/share/gnome-pomodoro/.
You can also check configuration files in ~/.config/gnome-pomodoro/.
